# iOS updateView called after viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I have a `NavigationViewController` with a `UITableView` in it. Upon load, I make an asynchronous backend server call to get some data to populate the view. Upon return I would call `updateView`.

I found that sometimes I would only see the Navigation Bar appear and no table view. From my debugging, this occurs when my `updateView` gets called **AFTER** `viewDidAppear`.

I do have a `[self.taboleView reloadData]` at the end of my `updateView` but I guess that doesn't help when `viewDidAppear` has already fired?

Bit confused about this.
Anybody have any idea how to solve this timing issue?

This is happening on an iPhone with iOS8.

Thanks!

Comment: Since it's a asynchronous server call, the app goes on executing the main thread (I think). Don't you have a delegate function in your asynchronous library that is called when the server answer arrives?

Comment: Change asynchronous request to a synchronous request and then tell me if it makes any difference.

Comment: You definitely want to keep it async, so the way I've always dealt with this is start the request in viewWillAppear, put up some sort of loading indicator on screen, and then when the request comes back get rid of the loading indicator and reload your view. Simple as that.

Comment: @Mike makes sense! This might be another question but any ideas why [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:self.view waitUntilDone:TRUE]; is throwign an 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' exception? I guess that's what you mean when you say to 'reload your view'.

Comment: No, if it is a table view all you need to do is `[self.tableView reloadData];`.

Comment: @Mike I am indeed doing this at the end of my updateView method but still nothing is showing up. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling updateView and [self.taboleView reloadData] on the mainthread?

Comment: @TobiasOlofsson Yep that was it. The last missing piece of the puzzle was to call [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:TRUE]; Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to reload/update the view on the main thread. 
So at the end of my `updateView`
I changed my `[self.tableView reloadData]` to

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:TRUE];
```

And it fixed my bug!